# Given a class member name or object, how can I find its declaring/enclosing class object in java?

Tags: java

It looks like that given a Field or Element, we can use getEnclosingClass or getDeclaringClass, but not the member itself.  If we can turn a member into a feild, we could solve this.  Anyone know?

Specifically, for the following code snippet:

```
@DoBinding
public Class Foo{

  static String bar=MyUtil.bindValue(bar);

.....
}
```

In the bindValue method, I need to find the class Foo to see if it has annotation DoBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caller's context is not available through "normal" code, but you can interrogate the call stack to find the class that invoked the method.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

I think you'll find it at index `2` (index `0` is the current line's and `1` is the current method's details).

```
String className = stackTraceElements[2].getClassName();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
```

Comment: this is nice, and it actually is at 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do that automatically, but couldn't you do:

```
static String bar=MyUtil.bindValue(this, bar);
```

?

Comment: It would be OK, if java let "this" used in a static context.  I had to hardcode the class name as using Foo.class.  The stack trace hints look something to try out.

Answer (score 0):

The `bindValue` method actually has no orthodox way of finding out anything about its caller, unless it's a `SecurityManager`, when it can call `getClassContext()[0]`. But don't do that.

It seems like you are somewhat confused. What is passed to `bindValue` has no information about where it is declared, all that is passed is the value.

Instead, how about the honor system, where you forget about checking for the `@DoBinding` annotation and just do something.

Or, if it really matters, just pass a `boolean` for the same purpose as `@DoBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out an example based on the `StackTrace` method. Let me know if anything is unclear, the other answers already provide some good information about why this is needed. The implementation is fairly straightforward.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        System.out.println(f.x);
    }
}

@Deprecated
class Foo {
    static String x = StaticClass.doSomething();
}

class StaticClass {
    static String doSomething(){
        StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

        String result = ""; 
        for(int i = 0; i < trace.length; i++){
            if(trace[i].getClassName().startsWith((StaticClass.class.getCanonicalName()))){             
                result = trace[i + 1].getClassName();
            }
        }

        Class<?> c = null;
        try {
            c = Class.forName(result);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Annotation s : c.getAnnotations()){
            if(s.toString().contains("Deprecated")) { System.out.println("Deprecate annotation found!"); }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Deprecate annotation found!
>   Foo